# ASP.NET VB WebMethod in aspx.vb page - failing but works in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert an Amazon Pay SDK example project to VB. It runs just fine in C# when compiled, but the VB conversion I made is failing.
The original c# project I am working with can be found here: [AmazonPay SDK Samples][1]. I am working with the C# object and only the OneTimePayments code.

The C# code that works just fine is this:
ASPX PAGE Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SetPaymentDetails.aspx/MakeApiCallAndReturnJsonResponse",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
         amazonOrderReferenceId: oro,
         amount: "19.95",
         addressConsentToken: access_token
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
         $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
              if (key == "getOrderReferenceDetailsResponse") {
                    $("#get_details_response").html(value);
              }
              else if (key == "setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse") {
                    $("#setOrderReferenceDetailsResponse").html(value);
              }
         });
    }
});
```

And the receiving c# code in the aspx.cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Dictionary<string, string> MakeApiCallAndReturnJsonResponse(string amazonBillingAgreementId, string amount, string addressConsentToken = "")
{
    SetOrderReferenceDetailsApiCall(amazonBillingAgreementId);
    GetOrderReferenceDetailsApiCall(amazonBillingAgreementId);
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("amazonBillingAgreementId", amazonBillingAgreementId);
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("amount", amount);
    return apiResponse;
}
```

The page in VB has the exact same JavaScript. The receiving code in the aspx.vb page is:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Function MakeApiCallAndReturnJsonResponse(ByVal amazonBillingAgreementId As String, ByVal amount As String, ByVal addressConsentToken As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    SetOrderReferenceDetailsApiCall(amazonBillingAgreementId)
    GetOrderReferenceDetailsApiCall(amazonBillingAgreementId)
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("amazonBillingAgreementId", amazonBillingAgreementId)
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("amount", amount)
    Return apiResponse
End Function
```

When the VB version is run and the AJAX call is made to the WebMethod, the error returned is:

> Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
> 'amazonBillingAgreementId'. at
> System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
> target, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams) at
> System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
> context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)

I have been stuck on this for a day and finally decided to see if anyone here can help.

Thank you in advance.
[1]: https://amzn.github.io/amazon-pay-sdk-samples/login_and_pay/lpa-login.html

Comment: Try removing ByVal as see what happens.  Class objects in c# are passed as ref.

Comment: If I remove the ByVal I get this error back form the AJAX call:
Invalid JSON primitive: amazonOrderReferenceId
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()…..

Comment: @jdweng: Class objects in C# are passed by ref when using the "ref" keyword - exactly the same as using "ByRef" in VB. Both allow redirecting the reference to another object. When not using 'ref' or 'ByRef', only the object internal properties can change.

Comment: @jdweng *Class objects in c# are passed as ref* - this is either "not necessarily, true" or "yes, and they are in vb too". You might want to look into things a bit more because at a guess you seem to believe in some non-existent stark difference between the way c# and vb.net pass method arguments

Comment: And WHERE is apiResonse being set here?

Comment: After a lot more tests and playing, the issue SEEMS to be in the webmethod return of a Dictionary(Of String, String). This is returning "The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary."
How is c# able to handle it but not VB? What can I use that will work?

Comment: Does the c# code actually work? Where and how is apiResponse being set here? You not provided that part of the code. What is the scope of apiResponse? Is that a external function? You not provided that code part.

Comment: The c# code given by Amazon works. I finally got a translation working but had to move the webmethods out of the aspx page and into an asmx page.